# How to integrate CUDA into an existing class structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

I have a working CPU-based implementation of a simple deep learning framework where the main components are nodes of a computation graph which can perform computations on tensors.

Now I need to extend my implementation to GPU, I would like to use the existing class structure and only extend its functionality to GPU however, I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Most of the classes have methods that work on and return tensors such as:

```
tensor_ptr get_output();
```

where `tensor_ptr` is simply `std::shared_ptr` pointer of my tensor class. Now what I would like to do is to add a GPU version for each such method. The idea that I had in mind was to define a `struct` in a separate file `tensor_gpu.cuh` as follows

```
struct cu_shape {
    int n_dims;
    int x,y,z;
    int len;
};

struct cu_tensor {
    __device__ float * array;
    cu_shape shape;
};
```

and then the previous function would be mirrored by:

```
cu_tensor cu_get_output();
```

The problem seems to be that the `.cuh` file gets treated as a regular header file and is compiled by the default c++ compiler and gives error:

```
error: attribute "device" does not apply here
```

on the line with the definition of `__device__ float * array`.

I am aware that you cannot mix CUDA and pure C++ code so I planned to hide all the CUDA runtime api functions into `.cu` files which would be defined in `.h` files. The problem is that I wanted to store the device pointers within my class and then pass those to the CUDA-calling functions.

This way I could still use all of my existing object structure and only modify the initialization and computation parts.

If a regular c++ class cannot touch anything with `__device__` flag then how can you even integrate CUDA code into C++ code?

Can you only use CUDA runtime calls and keywords literally just in `.cu` files?

Or is there some smart way to hide the fact from c++ compiler that it is dealing with CUDA pointers?

Any insight is deeply appreciated!

EDIT: There seems to be a misunderstanding on my part. You **don't** need to put the `__device__` flag and you'll still be able to use it as a pointer to device memory. If you have something valuable to add to good practices on CUDA integration or clarify something else, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 1):

'__' is reserved for implementation purposes. That is why the Nvidia implementation can use  `__device__`. But the other "regular" C++ implementation has its own reserved symbols.

In hindsight Nvidia could have designed a better solution but that is not going to help you here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that? What do you mean by implementation purposes? Those attributes can be used within `.cu` files but not anywhere else. My guess would be that it is a valid attribute only for the nvcc compiler or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It's valid for nvcc. I have no idea what it does in python or java. That's the problem with words taken out of context. And even in C++, it's out of context - explicitly